# Is it better convention to make angularjs directives "attributes" or "elements"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When making angular directives, it seems there are a set directives that could just as reasonably be defined as an HTML element, or an attribute. I am trying to figure out what the community convention (if any) is around which one to pick, and why.

So for example, an attribute centric view may be:

```
<div list-container>
  <div list-filter/>
  <div list="listOptions"/>
</div>
```

and the same in a element style view:

```
<list-container>
   <list-filter />
   <list controller="listOptions" />
</list-container>
```

My personal preference is for the second one (seems easier to read, dont have to worry about spans vs divs, etc), but most of the examples and libraries i've seen seem prefer the attribute approach (makes for valid html?)

Comment: pretty much depends on browsers you want to support. Simpler to manage IE8 with attributes for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to support IE8 or below, forget elements. Attributes or class names is the way to go.

Otherwise, I think it largely depends on the type of directive:

- If the directive is meant to be used as a component, i.e. substantial functionality, has it's own template etc, I would go for an element. Examples are tab controls, accordions, calendar etc.
- If the directive is just about adding a small behavior to either a built-in element (input, select etc) or a custom directive of the first kind, I would make it an attribute.

Comment: In IE8 you can have elements as directives if and only if you add your directive name to html5 shiv and let IE8 know that there is a declaration for this.